# Force exit on upgrade

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I forced exit on Ubuntu upgrade and when I try a new command it gives me this

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a'
```

If I run that command will upgrade continue? If yes, how do I just do so it won't continue because I don't want to upgrade anything?

I read about removing files from `/var/lib/dpkg/updates` and that should solve the issue, but I don't want to try things out of the blue on Linux machines because that got me into troubles already.

Comment: @karel: I don't think the linked question addresses this question: **“If I run that command will upgrade continue? If yes, how do I just do so it won't continue because I don't want to upgrade anything?”**

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to explain how *exactly* you attempted to upgrade Ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: Close voters: Crafting an answer.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I noticed the difference but it looks like the view from the bow of an icebreaker ship that is sailing through water that has some floating ice. I think the linked question has enough power to sail smoothly through the ice that is seen in front of it without getting stuck in it. There is a difference of opinion about what should or shouldn't be classified as a **hair splitting difference**.

Comment: @karel: I strongly disagree. If you think the linked question addresses this one you missed its point entirely. Although the *error message* is the same the *question* and the *underlying aim* of its author are *wildly different*. Please **read the *entire* question** and **don't try to “fix” things that its author clearly *doesn’t want fixed***.

Comment: Underlying aim of the author doesn't matter much if the two questions including answers are close enough duplicates anyway. **Strongly disagree** explains the capital letters in the comments because what else could it reasonably be? Saying I didn't read it is just plain wrong. In fact I did read it.

Comment: @karel: But the answers aren't the same. Not even close. Please compare the answer to your linked question with Elder Geek’s answer to this one.

Comment: Thank you David Foerster, appreciate the fact that you stood up for me. The correct answer is Elder Geek which I approved because it worked. Have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer** to your question is No.

**The longer answer is:**
`dpkg --configure -a` will likely repair the damage caused by the interruption you forced, so regardless of what you might be thinking you should do that. The upgrade process that you interrupted will not automatically resume or restart. However, repairing the damage as suggested to you by your system greatly increases the chance of success the next time you attempt to update and upgrade your system.

Comment: Thank you man, worked and I approved it also wish you a good day :)